# Withdraw my own edit suggestion

Tags: support, feature-request, suggested-edits

It seems that while editing another person's post (actually improving it by using MathJax), I realized - after having made my suggestion -  that I made some "mistakes" (see Edit 2) in the mathematical formula, which  I tried to format.

Though it can be rejected by those who have the privilege to approve/reject edits, I would like to know if I can withdraw it on my own.

**Edit 1**: Maybe this option could be added as a feature?

**Edit 2**: It seems that my suggestion is applied. The point is that the mathematical formula had not correct math syntax, so it was not clear what the OP meant. Hence, I am not able to make any suitable corrections, unless the OP corrects it himself/herself (rare in case of new users, who are unaware of MathJax).That's why I posted this question.

Comment: No, you can't withdraw it. Wait for it to be rejected or improved.

Comment: (It seems like you're already doing this, but definitely keep an eye on the edit - there's nothing to stop you from suggesting a correction to your own edit if it gets through review and is applied)